# Video Recording is too fast in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm capturing video from my video file  using OpenCV on linux. It works fine but when I try to play my captured video it plays too fast. i.e. I capture from video  for 10 seconds but when I play on  the video is 8 seconds.

**Video capture function**

```
def save_frames(video_file, path_in):
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
count = 1
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite(path_in + "frame{}.jpg".format(str(count).zfill(5)), frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    count += 1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
return fps
```

**Video writer function**

```
def make_video(path_out, outvid, fps=25, size=None, is_color=True,format='mp4v'):
images = [f for f in os.listdir(path_out) if ".png" in f]
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc, imread, resize
fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
vid = None
count = 0
for image in images:
    if not os.path.exists(path_out + image):
        raise FileNotFoundError(image)
    img = imread(path_out + image)
    if vid is None:
        if size is None:
            size = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
        vid = VideoWriter(outvid, fourcc, float(fps), size, is_color)
    if size[0] != img.shape[1] and size[1] != img.shape[0]:
        img = resize(img, size)
    vid.write(img)
    if count % 100 == 0:
        print("Progress: %0.2f%%" % (count / len(images) * 100,), flush=True)
vid.release()
return
```

I tried different fps (30,25,15,10,5) .These fps didn't works me and for all fps 600 frame captures  on 10 sec video .The cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS default capture 30 fps. When I try to change the fps but the frame rate didn't change .please let me know why this happens .Any answers welcome.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Can I see your main function? (The code you call save_frames() and make_video())

Comment: I add up the main fun...pls see that ....Is there any problem in cap_prop_fps function...i want to know how to select the frame rate

Comment: VideoCapture gives you the data as quickly as it can because OpenCV is not a video player, it's a library for computer vision. if you need "playback" to be at a certain speed, you have to vary the argument to waitKey according to when the next frame is due to be displayed. that means looking at wall clock time, knowing when a frame is due to be presented, and calculating the difference. -- or use a GUI toolkit that handles video presentation for you.

Comment: I vary the  wait key argument  to the capture and make video function .But it is same as before . Pls tell where to add the wait key in make_video function. I tried but don't work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

1)The problem here is **`cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS`** default fps is 30. So, it saves 600 images for 20sec video. To solve this  use **`if count%(1*fps) == 0:`** before the **`cv2.imwrite`** .It saves one frame for each second.

2)Then  set the `fps = 1` in **`VideoWriter`** object. After that video is in normal speed.